# Can't connect to Tor network

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

So I've been to several questions on this regarding some issues with people being inable to connect to the Tor network, yet I am still inable to connect.

After downloading the bundle I click 'Start Tor Browser' which brings me to the 'Tor Network Settings' window.  There are two options.  I always click the first which loads until it says 'Please wait while we establish a connect to the Tor Network', but it never finishes, ever.

The second option on the 'Tor Network Settings' is to complicated for me to work through on myself as I am not very experience with that type of stuff.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Could you provide the URL you used to download Tor, to make sure it's a recent and official version?

Comment: You could also turn off all other programs which use the Internet and use [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) to see if the browser is able to talk to *anything* (in the **Info** column you should see first a "Client Hello" and then a "Server Hello [...]" and then a bunch of "Application Data").

Comment: Do you have time to chat? I'd need some more information and the best would be to discuss this in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10754/the-exit-node Please let me know if this is feasible for you and when you'll have time for a chat.

Comment: I will be online all day today, so simply send me a message and we can surely chat.  Also, I downloaded the Tor bundle from the Tor website for Windows.  I installed it and clicked 'Star Tor Browser' and it gives me the 'Tor Network Settings' Window, with 2 options.  It looks like this: 

https://www.securityinabox.org/sites/siabnext.ttc.io/files/media/torbrowser-win-012.png

I click the first option and it only loads until it says 'Loading Network Status' but never finishes.

I am still not certain as to how to fix this.

Comment: I won't be able to enter the chat room unless I have a reputation or 20.  If you need more information you can always skype me.  My username is n0zark